# Move the highest value to start of list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Goal: move the highest value in `list` to `index: 0`, without re-ordering any other elements.

**What is the most Pythonic way to do this?**

Preferably:

- a one-liner,
- without imports

Example:

```
[0.013, 0.726, 0.22323, 5.08, 1.23432]
```

Desired Output:

```
[5.08, 0.013, 0.726, 0.22323, 1.23432]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a list comprehension based approach:

```py
inp = [0.013, 0.726, 0.22323, 5.08, 1.23432]
output = [max(inp)] + [x for x in inp if x != max(inp)]
print(output)  # [5.08, 0.013, 0.726, 0.22323, 1.23432]
```

This builds an output list whose first element is the max value in the input list, followed by that same input list with its max value removed.

Comment: Please consider upvoting this solution for others to find via. search engine.